# How To Identify button click of a node in dataTreeListView1 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I have dataTreeListView named dataTreeListView1 i wish to get the name of the node which i clicked can any one please help me to do this

[image]

in the above picture if i click yes i wish to get yes on messagebox

what i tried to do is

```
private void dataTreeListView1_AfterSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello");
        }
```

and the node are loaded dynamically means they are from database.

```
List<Class3> list = new List<Class3>();
                    list = Class3.GetList(startDate, endDate, con);
                    this.dataTreeListView1.ParentKeyAspectName = "ParentId";
                    this.dataTreeListView1.RootKeyValueString = "NUll";
                    BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn col = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn();
                    col.Width = 10;
                    dataTreeListView1.DataSource = list;
                    foreach (ColumnHeader column in this.dataTreeListView1.Columns)
                    {
                        column.Width = 140 + 140 + this.dataTreeListView1.SmallImageSize.Width;
                    }
                    this.dataTreeListView1.Columns.RemoveByKey("Id");
                    this.dataTreeListView1.Columns.RemoveByKey("ParentId");
```

this is how i show data in datatreelist view

```
 public Class3()
        {
            this.xName = "";
            this.xId = "";
            this.xParentId = "";
            this.xcredit = 0.0M;
            this.xdebit = 0.0M;
            this.xx = 0.0M;
            this.xy = 0.0M;
        }

        public String Ledger
        {
            get { return this.xName; }
            set { this.xName = value; }
        }

        public String Id
        {
            get { return this.xId; }
            set { this.xId = value; }
        }

        public String ParentId
        {
            get { return this.xParentId; }
            set { this.xParentId = value; }
        }

        public Decimal Credit
        {
            get { return this.xcredit; }
            set { this.xcredit = value; }
        }

        public Decimal Debit
        {
            get { return this.xdebit; }
            set { this.xdebit = value; }
        }
        public decimal x
        {
            get { return this.xx; }
            set { this.xx = value; }
        }
        public decimal y
        {
            get { return this.xy; }
            set { this.xy = value; }
        }
        public static List<Class3> GetList(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, SqlConnection con)
        {
            List<Class3> oList = new List<Class3>();
            Buisiness b = new Buisiness();
            try
            {
                decimal totalcredit = 0;
                decimal totaldebit = 0;
                con.Open();
                //    // Make sql readable
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string sql = @"Select Ledger.LedId,Ledger.LedName,Ledger.MasterLedger from Ledger where Ledger.Date >= @prmStartDate and Ledger.Date <= @prmEndDate group by Ledger.MasterLedger,Ledger.LedId,Ledger.LedName";

                // wrap IDisposable (SqlCommand) into using
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;
                    SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (da.Read())
                    {
                        Class3 oClass = new Class3();
                        oClass.Ledger = da["LedName"].ToString();
                        oClass.Id = da["LedId"].ToString();
                        oClass.ParentId = da["MasterLedger"].ToString();
                        Dictionary<string, decimal> d = b.findclosingbalanceofledger(da["LedId"].ToString());
    /*                    if (da["MasterLedger"].ToString() == "NUll")
                      {
                            oClass.Debit = findsumofallchilds(da["LedId"].ToString(), con, startDate, endDate);
                        }
                       else
                       {*/
                            if (d.FirstOrDefault().Key == "debit")
                            {
                                d.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
                                d.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
                                totaldebit = totaldebit + d.FirstOrDefault().Value;
                                oClass.Debit = d.FirstOrDefault().Value;
                            }
                            else if (d.FirstOrDefault().Key == "credit")
                            {
                                d.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
                                totalcredit = totalcredit + d.FirstOrDefault().Value;
                                oClass.Credit = d.FirstOrDefault().Value;
                            }
  /*                      }*/
                        oList.Add(oClass);


                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exe.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return oList;
        }
```

i have changed my code this

```
 private void dataTreeListView1_AfterSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hello");
            }
```

to

```
private void dataTreeListView1_CellClick(object sender, CellClickEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("helo");
}
```

but no change

Comment: What is the run-time type of `object sender`?

Comment: @Enigmativity  i dont'know how to know it

Comment: It's easy - `sender.GetType()`. Do a `.FullName` on this and tell me what you get.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for new information

Comment: @Enigmativity BrightIdeasSoftware.DataTreeListView  I get this output when i did above on this function private void dataTreeListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        } not in function in question

Comment: Did you try putting a break point inside event handler in question and inspecting `sender` or `e` to check if any selected item passed along?

Comment: @SivaGopal  Yes but program is not breaking even i put break point

Comment: i understand this is not the correct event handler can any please help me to find it

Comment: I do not see that you registered for any event.

Comment: @o_weisman i thought that dataTreeListView1_CellClick is an event listner like  private void metroButton6_Click  correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I believe you are wrong. dataTreeListView1_CellClick is a function. In order to make it a handler, you need to somewhere register it as a handler something like:  `dataTreeListView1.CellClick += this.dataTreeListView1_CellClick;` . Assuming of course that dataTreeListView1 has a CellClick event (I don't know its type or even the framework)

Comment: @o_weisman register a handler will it work. what i mean is if register an event will i get output

Comment: If you register on the correct event, your handler should be called

Comment: @o_weisman okey i will try to do it.